# Lookahead assertions in Go

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to convert a couple of Python regular expressions into Go.  The issue I'm having is the lack of support for lookahead assertions in Go.

How do I convert these two regular expressions into Go?

```
/*                                                                              
Format of a regular expression to find contexts including possible              
sentence boundaries. Matches token which the possible sentence boundary         
ends, and matches the following token within a lookahead expression             
*/                                                                              
const periodContextFmt string = `                                               
\S*                         # some word material                                
{{.SentEndChars}}           # a potential sentence ending                       
(?=(?P<after_tok>                                                               
{{.NonWord}}                # either other punctuation                          
|                                                                               
\s+(?P<next_tok>\S+)        # or whitespace and some other token                
))` 

// Format of a regular expression to split punctuation from words, excluding period.
const wordTokenFmt string = `(                                                  
{{.MultiChar}}                                                                  
|                                                                               
(?={{.WordStart}})\S+?        # Accept word characters until end is found
(?=                                   # Sequences marking a word's end          
\s|                                   # White-space                             
$|                                    # End-of-string                           
{{.NonWord}}|{{.MultiChar}}|          # Punctuation                             
,(?=$|\s|{{.NonWord}}|{{.MultiChar}}) # Comma if at end of word                 
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|                                                                               
\S                                                                              
)`
```

Comment: These particular ones it looks like maybe you could turn into regular capturing groups, i.e., just remove the `?=`. Then you make the sentence-ender or word token you want to find a group, and use one of the `Submatch` functions to get its start and end. Since `All` functions find _non-overlapping_ matches and your former lookahead is now part of the match, you have to work around it: find the first match, then search again starting from the end of the last sentence/token you found.

Comment: (In other words, all I can think of are the language-independent workarounds for not having lookahead at all.)